# Command to show set prefix in discord.py (rewrite)

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a help command that sends the current server-prefixes for the bot in an embed. I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to code this, and I would love some help. I have tried doing:

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Help', description='', colour=discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.set_footer(text='Have fun!')

    prefix = command_prefix

    embed.add_field(
        name='Prefix',
        value=
        f'The current prefix for this server is {prefix}',
        inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

However when I do this I get the error:

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'command_prefix' is not defined
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated. (:

Comment: You need to define `command_prefix` to do `prefix = command_prefix`.

Comment: Like this, `async def help(ctx, command_prefix):`?

Comment: No, that's not what you need, you need to save and send these prefixes in a file automaticly.

Comment: So I could use json data to display it?

Comment: Yes, if you are doing this bot for multiple guilds, or if you want to print out the prefix or if you want to change the prefix with a command, you need to save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a prefix variable that you can then display in the help command and change later:

```
prefix="!!"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Help', description='', colour=discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.set_footer(text='Have fun!')

    embed.add_field(
        name='Prefix',
        value=
        f'The current prefix for this server is {prefix}',
        inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested in the question, you can do:

```
client.commmand_prefix #if u use bot, just use bot.command_prefix
```

in this case it would be:

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Help', description='', colour=discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.set_footer(text='Have fun!')

    prefix = command_prefix

    embed.add_field(
        name='Prefix',
        value=
        f'The current prefix for this server is {bot.command_prefix}',
        inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```